# ssh using key of the remote host

Tags: ssh

Say I want to ssh using key from client to a server. On the server, this key exists /home/alice/.ssh/id_rsa. Can I copy this key file to the client and use it to ssh to the server client like:

[john@clienthost] ssh -i /path/to/alice/id_rsa alice@server

Comment: No. The client should generate a new key.

Comment: I mean, you *can*, but you shouldn't. Keys are easy to create, and you shouldn't copy or reuse private keys in this fashion.

Comment: Assuming openssh, it is the contents of `authorized_keys` on the server that determines which private key may be used for access.